# asp.net mvc ajax post traditional parameter serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm using kendo-ui's treeview.

I need to refresh the treeview after inserting a new treenode. For the sake of user friendliness, I want to make the treeview to auto expand to the newly created treenode by giving three parameters to the method responsible for creating the treeview's JSON. You can see the code for that below.

```
treeview.dataSource.transport.options.read.data = {
    showInactiveItems: $("#ShowInactiveAreas").find('i').hasClass('icon-eye-close'),
    selectedAreaId: areaId,
    selectedAreaType: areaType,
    ancestry: ancestry
};
treeview.dataSource.read();
```

So I am planning to pass array of parent IDs (ancestry) to the method so that the method knows which one to set the expand property to true.

If it was a jQuery I know how to do that with jQuery.makeArray(ancestry) and set the traditional parameter serialization to true in the $.ajax(). But this is kendo.

Does anyone know how to make the treeview.dataSource.read() to do traditional param serializing?

Or how to make asp.net mvc 4.0 to accept ajax post parameter such as

```
ancestry[]  Indonesia
ancestry[]  Aceh
```

It seems asp.net MVC doesn't support "[]" in parameter names unlike PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I cannot insist to post data. I have to switch method to use urlencoded parameter using jQuery.param

```
    treeview.dataSource.transport.options.read.data = {
            showInactiveItems: $("#ShowInactiveTerritories").find('i').hasClass('icon-eye-close'),
        selectedTerritoryId: territoryId,
        selectedTerritoryType: territoryType,
    };
    query = "?" + jQuery.param({ ancestry: ancestry }, true);
    treeview.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = loadurl + query;
    treeview.dataSource.read();
```

Worked!